# How can I capture the output of a command as a String with Commons Exec?

Tags: java

Commons exec provides a PumpStreamHandler which redirects standard output to the Java process' standard output. How can I capture the output of the command into a String?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

He're what I found:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.Executor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler;

public String execToString(String command) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CommandLine commandline = CommandLine.parse(command);
    DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
    PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);
    exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
    exec.execute(commandline);
    return(outputStream.toString());
}
```

Comment: For a long-running task, I want to display the command line execution logs in real time on the front end. How should I collect real-time logs through OutputStream?