# Running exe file with arguments from java program and sending output to text file

Tags: java, arguments, exe

I want to run a exe file that accepts a mp3 file as an argument and redirects the output to a text file.

I am using the below command from command prompt and its running fine and making a log.txt file in my binary folder however I am unable to do so by java.

```
    C:\Users\Desktop\binary>codegen.exe kalimba.mp3 > log.txt
```

I have tried the ProcessBuilder class however cannot see the log.txt made in the binary folder

```
 File f = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/binary");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c","start","codegen.exe", "kalimba.mp3", "log.txt");
pb.directory(f);
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991007/execute-external-program-in-java

Comment: Did any of the proposed solutions below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it done :)

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Users/Desktop/binary/codegen.exe", "C:/Users/Desktop/binary/Kalimba.mp3");

Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process .getInputStream())); 
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("D:/log.txt");
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("global");
logger.addHandler(fh);
SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(formatter);
String line = null;
while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, line);
}
System.out.println("Logging Completed...");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ProcessBuilder` itself to redirect the output to a file. Specifically, the [`redirectOutput(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.io.File%29) method:

```
final File outFile = new File(...);
pb.redirectOutput(outFile);
```

The redirection using `>` (in `cmd` as well as with Unix shells) is handled by the command interpreter/shell.

Comment: Actually I have to run it in JDK version 6 and that doesnt have the redirectOutputMethod as its newly added.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question ;)

Comment: Yea forgot. Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Apache's *Commons Exec* as an alternative. It's very intuitive and easy to work with, plus it's friendly with different platforms.

Take a look a the [Tutorial](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html) and see if it suits your needs.
If so, take a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295866/how-can-i-capture-the-output-of-a-command-as-a-string-with-commons-exec) about how to capture the output stream of the resulting `Process` from the command.

If using `ProcessBuilder` is a requirement, take a look at the example on `ProcessBuilder`'s [Documentation Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). It shows exactly what you want.