# Launch a script from a .jar

Tags: java

I've created a .jar in which I have a script named init.sh

I got this error.

> tim@TS:~/Desktop$ java -jar test.jar
> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/init.sh": error=2, No such file or directory
> at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:621)
> at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:486)
> at Main.run(Main.java:42)

My code which works when I run on Eclipse is below.

> ```
> String[] cmd = {"src/init.sh"};
>       try {
>       Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
>   } catch (IOException e) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>       e.printStackTrace();
>   }
> ```

I've tried to change it without success like that.

> ```
>   String[] cmd = {"init.sh"};
> ```

I looked at my .jar file and the init.sh script is at the same level as the Main.class.

My question is : **How must I change my code if I want to get a functional .jar ?**

Answer (score -3):

Based on the answer here [Executing a shell script inside a jar file. How to extract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603807/executing-a-shell-script-inside-a-jar-file-how-to-extract), looks like the shell script needs to be extracted to a location outside the jar file before you can execute it.

Comment: Really ? It's not possible to let the script inside the .jar generated ?