# How do i run a UNIX terminal from Java and send commands to it?

Tags: java, shell, unix, terminal

Regarding the topic, the code below

---

```
    Process proc = null;
    try {
        String[] cmdss= {"gnome-terminal"};


        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdss, null, wd);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

Runs the terminal form Ubuntu.

How do I issue commands into the terminal after running the termnal?

eg: running the terminal and run command such as "ls" etc.

Comment: You should do whatever you're trying to do in Java instead of using shell commands.

Comment: hi, i would love to do that but i do not think that's an option for me. This is because apart from running the scripts, user may need to input commands such as y/n into the terminal after running certain scripts. I am not sure how to do that from java interface.

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do? You should ask a separate question?

Comment: an example: running a fortran program from java.  If i would run the fortran program entirely from java exec, i have no problem with running it. However, the fortran program may prompt user for extra input. In this case, i do not think java is able to capture termninal  "waiting for input" state and prompt the use to enter data from java interface.

Comment: maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `gnome-terminal` some options on the command line what it shall execute.

```
gnome-terminal -e /my/fortran/program
```

The `-x` option gives you roughly the same benefit but you can split the commandline into separate words.

Both `-e` and `-x` run the program with optional arguments while connecting the program`s standard input and output to the terminal. So the user can interact with the terminal properly.

Example:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "ls; echo '<enter>'; read"
```

This will open the terminal and run the "program" `bash`. `bash` will get *two* arguments: `-c` and `ls; echo ....; read`. The `-c` option makes bash parsing and executing the next argument. This will call `ls`, then `echo ...` then `read` which waits for the return key.

In Java you must split the arguments appropriately into an array like this:

```
String cmd[] = {"gnome-terminal", "-x", "bash", "-c", "ls; echo '<enter>'; read" };
```

Comment: You also might consider using a program like expect so you can script the responses for interactive prompts; which seems like it's really what you're after.

Comment: Kevin, that was my real intention. However, i have no clue how to do that since i am a .Net/Windows based programmer but not a java/Unix programmer. So i am completely clueless on "expect" thing.

Comment: I understand the description at least partially.  "[I]t works exactly like i wanted" surprises me a bit, because I don't recognize in what's described much of a model for the user-interaction-with-Fortran that I thought Melvin specified.  In any case, it's possible to manage interaction with a Fortran-coded process either through a terminal, or as a direct subprocess of Java; I *strongly* favor the latter.  There's abundant Expect help around for you, Melvin.  http://expectj.sourceforge.net/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expect, and http://wiki.tcl.tk/expect might interest you.