# Is it Possible to Run shell script in java

Tags: java, shell

Is it possible to Run Shell script in java program. I am using windows XP as my operating system.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to run a shell script **in** Java.  However, you can run the script **from** Java, provided that the shell is installed on your machine along with the commands mentioned in the shell script.

I take it that you want to run a UNIX shell script on your Windows XP machine.  If that is the case, you need to install something like Cygwin.

Comment: Can i use Cygwin as a part of my java Application. if i want to use sme application on different machine without installing Cygwin. Is it possible.

Comment: No.  It is not possible.  You will need to rewrite the script as a BAT file that uses native windows commands.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, take a look at Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

I believe this question is duplicate of below post

[How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)