# Eclipse Java Unit tests

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, batch-file

Is there a way to execute `batch` script before each unit-test?  I've looked up the launch options for the test project, but I couldn't find any way to run any script

the script is a single line, which should be able to interface the android via `adb`

Comment: I think you can use Shunit for that (it's junit but for shell scripts)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JUnit, annotate a class with the @before tag and that class will be executed before every test case. In order to run a script look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167355/how-to-run-a-script-from-java)

Answer (score 1):

Here a short summary of the some usefull annotations in junit:

JUnit 4 führt sechs unterschiedliche Annotationen ein:

```
@Test - kennzeichnet Methoden als ausführbare Testfälle.
@Before und @After - markieren Setup- bzw. Teardown-Aufgaben, die für jeden Testfall wiederholt werden sollen.
@BeforeClass und @AfterClass - markieren Setup- bzw. Teardown-Aufgaben, die nur einmal pro Testklasse ausgeführt werden sollen.
@Ignore - kennzeichnet temporär nicht auszuführende Testfälle.
```

Source: http://www.frankwestphal.de/JUnit4.0.html

Comment: Since the unit-test runs on the device, I don't think I'll be able to interface the ADB, anyway, Ill give it a try. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you run **Android JUnit tests** they are run on the device or emulator via the test runner.

So if you try to run a script inside your JUnit tests it will also be run on the device or emulator, which is *most probably* not your intention.

Comment: If I knew what you are trying to achieve I could be clearer, but I don't know your objective.