# Integrating Shell Script and JSP

Tags: jsp, shell, integration

How can I integrate a shell script with jsp? I want to write a jsp and that jsp should be able to run shell scripts. How can I do the integration of both?

Answer (score 1):

See
[How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)

You can do this from Java scriptlet inside of JSP and use the ProcessBuilder class to achieve what you want
http://www.jsptut.com/Scriptlets.jsp

Usual suggestion of avoiding this (since it is costly to exec the shell process and also might be a maintenance and portability overhead) goes..I am sure there might be a good reason (legacy?) you want it :-)