# How to run bash script from Java

Tags: java, exception, process, cygwin

I've seen many similar posts but I am still stumped.  I want to run this shell script with a Java program :

```
C:\\Users\\pro-services\\Desktop\\projects\\github\\cygwin\\TEST.sh
```

Here's what the code looks like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\pro-services\\Desktop\\projects\\github\\cygwin\\TEST.sh");
Process p = pb.start();
```

I am trying to use `Process Builder` but I'm not sure how to get it to work - I keep getting the error:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Users\pro-services\Desktop\projects\github\cygwin\TEST.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I know there are other fields of `ProcessBuilder` that I'm not using.  I also know that there may be syntax issues here.  I wrote my script for Cygwin.  Any help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Unix shell script from java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the script as an executable to [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), pass in the path to [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) binary and pass your script as argument:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\path\\to\\bash.exe", "C:\\Users\\pro-services\\Desktop\\projects\\github\\cygwin\\TEST.sh");
Process p = pb.start();
```