# How to execute java code using shell script?

Tags: java, shell

> Possible duplicate "[How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)".

I would like to know how to execute java code using shell script?

I want to know is :

```
shell script executes java code.
```

I don't want to know is

```
java code executes shell script.
```

- My OS version is `cent0s 5.5 (64-bit)`.

Comment: You need to fire up the compiler and then run the JVM. Is this what you want?

Comment: Simple java -jar your_jar.jar or javac your_class would work. or you mean something else?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, I want to run .sh file and these file run java program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in, like this you mean?

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar your-java-compiled-into-a.jar
```

Comment: According to your answer, do i need to compile java class?

Comment: Yes, the JVM can only run bytecode (.class files). You can pack it into a Jar like Tom said.

Comment: If you don't want to compile but still use the JVM you need to avoid java and use one of the scripting languages that can run on the JVM such as ruby (jruby), javascript (rhino), groovy...

Comment: If you don't have a jar, just do `java Foo` to execute Foo.class