# Script to run .jar file on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, batch-file

I want to run batch file (similar to Windows) on Mac OS X to run a jar file, after search I found it run batch script.

I am not getting proper link from where I can take help.  How can I create this?

Comment: just re-write that .bat file to .sh file, if it is not complex

Comment: You have at least 3 options to consider on the Mac: shell scripts, Applescript programs, or Automator scripts.  They all have their various advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Does this app. have a GUI?  If so, there are far better alternatives than scripts to start it up.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes my app have GUI.

Comment: OK.  Well using a batch file to launch it is less than optimal.  This question is asked and answered.  I suggest you ask another question *"How to launch (easy for user) a Java GUI on multiple platforms?"*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could create a shell script and run it with Terminal.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar path/to/jar/file.jar
```

To run it you need to set up the right user permission, so do
    `chmod u+x script-name`
then run with
    `./script-name`

Comment: @Sam Thanks, I tried similar command before posting this, but that time I was trying with rtf file (I am changing its extension to sh), so unable to run shell script. Now tried with txt file, I was able to run.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a `shell script` on MAC OS to get the same result as with a batch file on Windows.

A `shell script` could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/java/jre-7x/bin/java -jar /your/path/to/jar-file
```

Please note that the path to the java executable depends on your java installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a batch file, but you [can run a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code) which is the equivalent on unix based systems.

Like the batch file, the shell script is also platform specific, but should work on Unix and Linux based systems.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files are Windows-only. However it should be easy to convert that batch file to a unix shell script. You find a guide on how to use shell scripts on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score -1):

you CAN'T , because its language specific.

you need to write shell script (or manually matching the windows commands with unix/mac os x commands)

Answer (score -1):

[Wine for Mac OS X](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/)

This would run windows programs on Mac OS X, try this and let me know.

Comment: This is likely hugely overkill / fragile if the bat file can be ported to a shell script easily (or written in Java itself.)

Comment: not that much, but i only posted so he/she could do it easily.