# How to run a .sh file from Java?

Tags: java, shell

I need to run a .sh file from my Java code with out passing any arguments. I already tried doing it with

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("src/lexparser.sh");
```

and

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("src/lexparser.sh");
Process p = pb.start();
```

Both of the above methods didn't work. Is there any other method to run a .sh file form Java?

Comment: What do you mean by _didn't work_ ?

Comment: make sure your .sh is executable

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: .sh file is not running.

Comment: are u on Linux or Windows?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code

Comment: will Biswajit's code given in answer help you to proceed?

Comment: @user2111009 Check that you are not missing shell environment vars at runtime.You may need to manipulate processBuilder.environment() for that

Comment: you are passing just String as argument in exec method, exec method except String[] argument. see my answer below, i have transerfred file successfuly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code/37327025#37327025

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("src/lexparser.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Process p = pb.start();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
 String line = null;
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
 {
    System.out.println(line);
 }
```

Comment: where are u using `Process p;` ?

Comment: to start processbuilder

Comment: I mean where are u using `p` reference variable in later code?

Comment: I have changed the code .plz check

Comment: OK. I got your corrections.

Comment: @Biswajit Can we execute a .sh file without providing arguements??

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that are easy to miss:

1. Path and CWD. The simplest way to ensure that the executable is found is to provide the absolute path to it, for example `/usr/local/bin/lexparser.sh`
2. Process output. You need to read the process output. The output is buffered and if the output buffer gets full the spawned process will hang.

Comment: I kept the .sh file in my project folder. My .sh file should read a file and update the contents of another file. It's working file when am running it directly from terminal but not from a java file

Comment: +1 for the Path issue.  I believe that there's an exec() method that can take in the working directory as the last argument (and I think you can null out the rest if n/a)

Comment: @user2111009 I haven't spawned processes from Java in a long time, so I cannot give any more specific information than what I've already provided. Try setting the CWD explicitly from inside the script (using `cd`).