# Run a bash script with "source XXXX.sh" by java

Tags: java, bash

How can I run more than one bash scripts and first of them, i will export some `PATH` args, I want to run ALL of them in Java. Yes it's "source XXX.sh" not "sh ..." or "./"

Comment: [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15428431/1706545

Comment: @Turing85 Does that preserve the variables that would be sourced in the first file between following executions?

Comment: I do not know for sure, but I would say no. If you need multiple calls, you could join them with `&&` inside your process.