# Java method to run a .sh file

Tags: java

I am developing a requirement where i hit a button which calls a java method at backend(updates rows in db).

There are 2 lists.
List A -->having more than 200000 records
List B-->having 1000 records

List A is obtained by running .sh file which runs a query(select query where rownum<10)
List B is directly obtained from DB.

If records from List B are present in List A then i update those records.
Challenge faced here is i do not have jdbc datsource so i cannot obtain List A directly but via .sh file.
Also, if i do not give rownum<10 then the execution takes more than 10 mins which is not acceptable.

so i need to execute the .sh file for first 10 records , compare it with List B, update the records if present in List A and then the same needs to be done for next 10 records and so on until all the records are compared.

Can you suggest something here?
Please let me know in case of any info needed.

Comment: Can you provide code, which you are using now to run .sh file?
Or you run it, and then run java app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a .sh file from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428414/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-java)

Answer (score 3):

I think that class [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) would be better idea, you can put arguments and control process and this is preferred way by Oracle since 1.5.

```
As of 1.5, ProcessBuilder.start() is the preferred way to create a Process.
```