# Mocking javax.mail.Transport

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, java-ee-7

Without creating another class that I can inject.  Is it possible to mock `javax.mail.Transport` so I can do some mock testing of the `Transport.send()` method on Java EE 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on Bill Shanon's solution since Dumbster does not have a currently working Maven Central artifact, I used GreenMail.

Then I used the following code:

```
final GreenMail mailServer = new GreenMail();
mailServer.start();

final Properties mailSessionProperties = new Properties();
mailSessionProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", String.valueOf(mailServer.getSmtp().getPort()));

final javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(mailSessionProperties);

testObject.setMailSession(mailSession);
```

That way `testObject` does not need to change even if it has a static call to `Transport.send(message)`.

Comment: The main advantage of using `GreenMail` is that your test can then verify that the expected email was sent. I've added in my tests things like this: `MimeMessage[] messages = mailServer.getReceivedMessages(); assertEquals(1, messages.length, "Failed to receive registration email"); assertEquals(1, messages[0].getHeader("To").length, "Malformed To headers in received registration email"); assertEquals(user.getEmail(), messages[0].getHeader("To")[0]);`

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to **not** call Transport.send while testing then you could use this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(javax.mail.Transport.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        suppress(method(Transport.class, "send", Message.class));
    }
}
```

see also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/powermock/r26PLsrcxyA

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that hasn't been discussed is to wrap calls to Transport.send(message) in a class that delegates the call. It's a bit of overhead in your code base, but it allows you to mock your delegating class and create the outcomes you want.

```
public class TransportDelegator {
    public void send(Message msg) throws MessagingException {
        Transport.send(msg)
    }
}
```

Then mock TransportDelegator as you would in whatever framework you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  On way is to use Mockito.  https://code.google.com/p/mockito/

```
public class CategoryDAOTest {

    private Transport transport = Mockito.mock(Transport.class);

    @Test
    public void sendMessage() throws MessagingException {
        transport.sendMessage(null, null);
    }
}
```

Or, using annotations to create the mock:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryDAOTest {

    @Mock
    private Transport transport;

    @Test
    public void sendMessage() throws MessagingException {
        transport.sendMessage(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is only on the test, but if "Transport" is used inside the implementation class, then it won't be testable.

Comment: Inject your mock into the class that uses it, before testing that class-- which is actually the most common way to use mocks.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new wrapper class and Mocked it with Mockito. This prevented me from adding PowerMock to my project.

```
public class MyTransport{
  public void send(MineMessage msg) throws MessagingException{
    javax.mail.Transport.send(msg);
  }
}
```

In side test class we just need

```
@Mock
private MyTransport myTransport
```

This will do nothing when is called.
You may also want to verifiy myTransport is getting called.

```
Mockito.verify(myTransport).send(correctMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a fake SMTP server such as [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/).  The JUnit tests in the JavaMail source workspace use a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JavaMail Mock2 https://github.com/salyh/javamail-mock2

It primarily focused on IMAP/POP3 but SMTP Mock is also available.
In your case the "Fullmock" mode is a good choice. Its also available in maven central.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux / osx you can use python to create a mock smtp server, like that:

python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025

Then it is enough if you connect to port 1025 on localhost and you can send emails. The Python code can be started by simple ProcessBuilder call ([How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)).

Answer (score 0):

This is How I did after hours of research, I was sending a list of attachments paths along with email to my method. everything workd fine

```
@Test
public void testWhenMigrationReportSentSuccessfully() throws Exception {
    mockStatic(Transport.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Transport.class, "send", any(Message.class));
    service.report(anyList(), "client@dummy.com");
}
```

Comment: what dependencies are needed for PowerMockito?

Comment: PowerMockito is a buggy library, conflicts with the latest Mockito 4.