# Calling shell script from java program and passing arguments to a shell script from java for loop

Tags: java, mysql, shell

Does anyone know if it is possible to call a shell script from within Java program and also pass an argument to that shell script from the for loop of that java class? In my shell script I am setting MySQL system variables to different values to see if those values affect the performance of the database application. I could have set those values through JDBC, but as I am working with MySQL, it is not possible to restart the database from JDBC, after each query execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. For something like this you would probably be better off just using a batch file or something to do it though.

If you really do need to use java try:

[How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec()` is what you are looking for.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("theScript.sh param1 param2);
```

..modulo exception handling.

You may want to look into [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/)