# Exec not return

Tags: java, cmd, label, exec

I am trying to execute a label cmd comand from java, but when I call exec and wait for the end of the process it freezes. What do you think is the problem?

```
    String[] comand = {"cmd.exe","label D: CIAO"};
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc;

    try {
        proc = rt.exec(comand);     
        int exitCode=proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println(exitCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: More than likely, your process writes a lot of stuff to stdout; but it blocks because it cannot write anymore. You need to read from this process' output. Also, use a `ProcessBuilder`, not `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: Check your task manager to make sure the process (cmd.exe) has actually exited.

Comment: Did you execute the same command manually from commandline? Does it take more time to execute with the same options/input? I suspect the executable takes longer to finish, which gives an impression that program freezes.

Comment: in DOS too 'cmd' does not return; you should run `cmd /C command` (check cmd.exe /?)

Comment: Out of the question : You can use [Apache commons exec](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793314/1686291)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, if you just execute the CMD or COMMAND by itself it will start it own "shell" window and will not return.  You have to use the /c to tell it to execute the command and return.  For Windowz NT and better it should be  `CMD.exe /c your_command` and for Windowsz 95 or worst, it should be `COMMAND.com /c your_command` and to check use the following Java codes:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if (os.indexOf("windows 9") > -1) {
  cmd = "CMD.exe /c";
} else if ((os.indexOf("nt") > -1) || (os.indexOf("windows 2000") > -1) || (os.indexOf("windows xp") > -1)) {
  cmd = "COMMAND.com /c";
}
```