# Triggering a shell script in another host machine

Tags: java

I am new to java and from eclipse ( in windows ), i would like to trigger a shell script in a remote unix server. The shell script must run in the Unix server ; but the triggering must happen from the java code in Windows. How can I do this ?

I have tried SSHExec ; but I am getting "SSHExec type cannot be resolved to a type." error.
Am I missing some import statements ? IF so, which will be the suitable import for this ?

Comment: How can we know what you're missing if you haven't posted any code?

Comment: refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793314/1686291) for triggering shell script from java code, to trigger that on remote machine you can use [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation), and for solution of your error, consider to post code here.

Comment: RMI seems like a way too complicated approach just to execute a remote command. I'd simply execute the "ssh..." command from within your Java application.

Comment: One more doubt pls ... Runtime.getRuntime() can be used only if the shell script and the java code resides in the same server ?