# How to automatically execute a script before each JUnit test execution?

Tags: eclipse, junit, environment-variables

My team is using JUnit to launch tests from eclipse.

Before executing these tests from eclipse, we have to specify the env variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to load dependencies at run time.
The correct value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH can change when one of my team's member commits a change in the project. We have a script which computes its correct value.

Today, we have two solutions to set the variable :

- run the script to get the value, and for each JUnit test we want to run, set it in Run Configurations window.
- write a script which sets the variable and launches eclipse.

First method is unproductive, and with second method, we have to restart eclipse each time we update the project.

A better solution would be to write a script which would set the variable and which would be called by eclipse each time a test is run.

Is there a way to call a script before each test with Eclipse ?
Any other idea would be also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Following the idea of the SO queston [How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code) you could execute a script before each test or each test class as follows

```java
@Before // could also be @BeforeClass
public void setupEnvViaScript() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("my-script.cmd", "arg-1", "arg-2");
  processBuilder.environment().put("JAVA_HOME", "value");
  processBuilder.environment().put("ENV_VAR", "value");

  processBuilder.directory(new File("d:/working/path/script/shall/be/executed/in"));
  Process process = processBuilder.start();

  int exitValue = process.waitFor();
  if (exitValue != 0) {
    // check for errors
    new BufferedInputStream(process.getErrorStream());
    throw new RuntimeException("execution of script failed!");
  }
}
```

This has some caveats

- this way it is platform depended
- the script and the path to it are hard-coded
- the working-directory is hard-coded

You could tackle this in several ways, like

- generate the script file on the fly before execution
- choose the execution path depended from some constraints

Comment: Wouldn't that simply start a separate process independent of the process running the junit? So that the separate process would not be able to affect the env of the junit process.