# Running Shell Script From External Directory: No such file or directory

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a shell script file that i want to run from java. My java work space directory is different than the script's directory.

```
private final String scriptPath = "/home/kemallin/Desktop/";

public void cleanCSVScript() {

    String script = "clean.sh";
    try {
        Process awk = new ProcessBuilder(scriptPath + script).start();
        awk.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and i get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cat /home/kemallin/Desktop/capture-03.csv | awk -F ',' '{ print $1,",", $2,",", $3,",", $4,",", $6}' > clean.csv": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at ShellScript.cleanCSVScript(ShellScript.java:21)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 2 more
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/kemallin/Desktop/clean.csv (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at CSVReader.run(CSVReader.java:25)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

I have googled it and every solution pretty much indicate that i'm doing the right thing.

I have tried to put the script file in the src and in bin of the Java project but still it says no such file or dir.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: java's trying to run your ENTIRE command line as a single command. The string `cat /home/...` is not a program, `cat` is, and the rest is an argument for cat.

Comment: Marc B is probably right, and I'm not a java guy, so what I would probably do is to check the permissions for `/home/kemallin/Desktop/capture-03.csv` and `/home/kemallin/Desktop/clean.sh`.  Make sure the user running the java program have access to those files (a+rwx if you just want to discard a permissions problem... if it is, then you can work from there)

Comment: I think your error output does not match the java code shown. In the Java code the command to run should be "/home/kemallin/Desktop/clean.sh" but in your error output shown appears "cat /home/kemallin/Desktop/capture-03.csv | awk..." and "/home/kemallin/Desktop/clean.csv" :(

Comment: @MarcB so what do you suggest? That I should break down the shell script?

Comment: @jim clean.sh have 755, user running the java program owns the clean.sh so accessing shouldn't be a problem is that correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your program `clean.sh` is not an executable as Java understands it, even though the underlying system understands it as executable.

You need to tell Java what shell is needed to execute your command. Do (assuming you are using `bash` and it is installed at `/bin/bash`):

```
private final String scriptPath = "/home/kemallin/Desktop/";

public void cleanCSVScript() {

    String script = "clean.sh";
    try {
        Process awk = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", scriptPath + script).start();
        awk.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed some part of the problem. Thank you I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: My mistake this fixed it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `chmod 755 /home/kemallin/Desktop/clean.sh` and ensure the java process is run under the same userid

Comment: It still says "no such file or directory".