# invoking node js from java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I want to invoke NODE JS from JAVA as below:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("swagger-to-raml-object","twitter-api-api-docsjson");
```

I am getting the following error:

```
CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

My path is properly set for `Node js.`

What is causing the issue?

Comment: What about the swagger-to-raml-object and any other file referenced by the program?

Comment: No other program referencing this.

Comment: You say you want to invoke nodejs but you're invoking swagger-to-raml-object. Is it invoking node internally? What kind of file is it?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647806/running-shell-script-from-external-directory-no-such-file-or-directory)) is execute the command `/bin/bash` and **your executable as the argument**.
This worked for me when I was trying to run a shell script... if you are able to run from command line `./my_super_exec` you can run the same from Java:

```
  /* Tell Java what shell is needed to execute your command */
  private static final String BIN_BASH = "/bin/bash";

  // ...

    int exitValue = 0;
    try {
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(BIN_BASH, sh);
      Process p = pb.start();
      exitValue = p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      return false;
    }
    return exitValue == 0;
```

Comment: @user3345282 great! If working, please check the answer as solved, or upvote it :)