# Java unable to execute a bash shell script

Tags: java

I'm running into trouble trying to compile the eXo platform.

The error message is:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/exo/platform-public-distributions-develop/plf-community-tomcat-standalone/target/platform-community-5.0.x-SNAPSHOT/platform-community-5.0.x-SNAPSHOT/addon" (in directory "/exo/platform-public-distributions-develop/plf-community-tomcat-standalone"): error=2, No such file or directory`

The directory is correct, the file indeed does exist, and permission is executable:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   3379 Sep  3 12:21 addon
```

That "addon" is a bash script.

I think the error mssage "No such file or directory" is erroneously reported. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647806/running-shell-script-from-external-directory-no-such-file-or-directory) answer, but it is telling us to change the source code. **Is there anyway to set some path for Java to execute the shell script?**

Comment: What do you mean "set some path"? The answer you linked to says to execute a separate bash subprocess which executes the script

Comment: I mean, like we have to set "JAVA_HOME" and something like that. I mean set something (not necessary path) to make it understand and execute shell scripts.

Comment: Could you paste your code please

Comment: All you need is executable permission and the path to the file, which you already have. You don't need an environment variable for shell scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash script probably has a shebang (`#!/bin/sh`) at the top. This is normally interpreted by bash when invoking the script. However, running from java is not going to do this automatically. You will need to *explicitly* invoke bash to run the script.

You didn't post your code, but you need to set bash (or `/bin/bash`) as the executable and make the script be the first argument to bash. This will explicitly invoke bash to run the script. You need to execute:

`/bin/bash /exo/platform-public-distributions-develop/plf-community-tomcat-standalone/target/platform-community-5.0.x-SNAPSHOT/platform-community-5.0.x-SNAPSHOT/addon`

Comment: It is an open source software package which I downloaded. I'd prefer not to search and change the code, but just build it as it is. So, instead of changing the source code, is there any other solution?

Comment: What OS are you using? Googling found a solution but it's for windows: https://community.exoplatform.com/portal/intranet/forum/topic/topic28d9bea89e4534520984d4a10d4ab26e

Comment: I'm running it on FreeBSD.

Comment: @ikevin8me Did you try the solution given in the link? Maybe it will work for you as well.

Comment: You mean the solution to add ".bat"? I'm not on Windows so I think it is not the solution.

Comment: Yup, I replaced the shebang (#!/usr/local/bin/bash) and it resolved my problem.