# Run bash file from java

Tags: java, linux, playframework

I want to run bash file from java, i am using play framework.
any idea how to do that??

is this code enough:

```
new ProcessBuilder("pathToYourShellScript").start();
```

Comment: how about running it to try before asking it?

Comment: i only have windows machine

Comment: I tested it, it's not working. Don't got a solution for you but you can test the code by download virtualbox and installing Linux on it. https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run Unix shell script from java code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code) (don't have the reputation to put that in a comment, sorry).

In a nutshell - your line of code will work and the shell script will run by just doing that (tested on a SUSE Linux box).

***However***, if you want to do anything with the output or to know that it has completed, you'll have to add more code to check its state (check out the [Process.waitFor() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)) or to capture its output in Java (e.g. by capturing Standard out in a BufferedReader) - check [Process.getInputStream() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29).