# Run an external shell or bat script from mule flow?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I would like to call/execute a shell script from a mule flow asynchronously . Also would like to know if we can call/execute a bat script

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could, in fact anything you can do with plain old Java you can do with Mule using the Java component.

Create a [Java component](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/java-component-reference) and place it within [Async scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/async-scope-reference)

Here a snippet of code to call a shell script using Java [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code) expands on it

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myshellScript.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");  
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();  
env.put("VAR1", "myValue");  
env.remove("OTHERVAR");  
env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");  
pb.directory(new File("myDir"));  
Process p = pb.start();
```

Comment: Is there any out of box component to call a script in mule ?

Comment: Most of the Mule components correspond to the EIP patterns a few others are hooks for custom logic, calling shell script is custom logic and so you won't find a mule processor just to do that, you could possibly write your own though

Comment: Having understood that mule is corresponding to EIP (which I am little aware already)which states how an endpoint can be constructed and how routing,validation,filters can be done. I wanted to know if there were any endpoints conforming to EIP standards to call or execute a system call to run a shell script or a bat file in mule already ?. From your comment I understand we don't have it . Please confirm you are aware of it.

Comment: Ya, I can confirm that