# Java: Convert command array to string that can execute in bash

Tags: java, bash, shell, escaping

I have a command in array format that I can pass to execve(). For example, the command is:

```
echo "It's Nice"
```

and the array I have is `["echo","It's Nice"]`. I'm trying to convert this array into a string that I can write in bash and execute properly. I obviously cannot join on this array with space delimiter because I will get: `echo It's Nice` which cannot be run since it has an unterminated single quote.

Is there a BKM to convert this to a runnable string? maybe a library that does that already in Java? It can get tricky when the command has many special characters that should be escaped\quoted in order to run properly.

EDIT:
I would like to make my question clearer. The user gives me his command as a string array, I execute it and everything works fine. Now I need to report to the user what I have ran. I do not want to show the command as an array, instead I would like to show it as a string that the user can simply copy and paste to his bash shell and execute it if he wants to. So my input is `[echo, It's Nice]` and my output should be `echo "It's Nice"`. It seems like a simple function to write, but i'm not sure i'm thinking of all the end-cases here (like if the string has a quote or some other special character the shell manipulates). I was wondering maybe there's some code that already does that and covers the end cases i'm yet to think about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert array to string, you can directly execute a command using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
String runShell(final String[] commandArgs) {   
    try {
        final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandArgs);
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true); // merge stderr with stdout
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        ret = process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                  process.getInputStream() ));
        br.lines().forEach(System.out::println); // print stdout + stderr
        process.destroy();
        br.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException|InterruptedException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    return commandArgs[0] + Arrays.asList(commandArgs).stream()
    .skip(1)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\" \"", " \"", "\""));
}
```

and call it as:

```
runShell(new String[] {"pwd"}); // print current working directory
runShell(new String[] {"ls", "-l"}); // list all the files and directories
runShell(new String[] {"echo", "It's Nice"}); // echo something
```

Comment: Actually i'm asking for reporting, i have no problem running the command but i want to tell the user what i ran and that he will be able to copy paste it to the shell if he needs to run it again

Comment: `processBuilder.command()` will give you the command that is being run

Comment: Will it give it even if i dont execute? Im running the command in a different way

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing your code. If you show your code then I can suggest something.

Comment: `processBuilder.command()` returns a list, in the third case above it will return `[echo , It's Nice]` when i actually need the string `echo "It's Nice"`. I will modify the question to make it clearer

Comment: It won't work, if some element in the array has a space it should be quoted, but if the string already contains quotes they should be escaped. the answer to this is not trivial, that's why i'm asking it here. i can write code that does what i described but there maybe more end-cases i haven't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy to do in Java 8:

```
String joined = String.join(" ", iteratable);
```