# Run an sh file from java code which contains kjb process call

Tags: java

I have a sh file with kettle process call. I am trying to trigger the sh file from Java code. I expect the sh process getting stopped with `destroy()` method in Java code after the kettle process successful completion.

Comment: From your question, it is not clear, what exactly the problem is. Please specify what you have tried and what your issues are. Then we are happy to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)