# Executing shell script from Java

Tags: java, shell, jar

Able to call and execute the shell script when executed in an individual Java Program. But there is no output when called from a Floodlight controller program

The Floodlight controller is executed using `java -jar target/floodlight.jar`. The command to execute the shell script is provided in one of the source files. When ever the condition matches and code gets executed, the terminal screen appears for a second and vanishes. But this is not the case when I execute the same shell script with Java in an individual program.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"path to shell script", arg1});
```

Can anybody please comment on this ?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)

Answer (score 0):

Executing with `sudo` or in `root` mode is the culprit. 
Ran in user mode, worked perfectly.