# Unable to call a shell script from Java where Shell contains sshpass

Tags: java, shell, unix, weblogic12c

We have an use case to transfer > 4GB data file from a sftp site to server box. We have decided to create a java service which will invoke a shell script that interns enter into the sftp site and path and get the file to the target destination.

We have wrote the following code to invoke shell script from Java file.

```java
Process proc = null;
String command = "/mnt/hmdata/loadTest.sh";
System.out.println("passing command::" + command);
try {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    proc = rt.exec(command.trim());
    boolean status = proc.waitFor `enter code here` (45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Shell Called successfully");
    if (status) {
        msg = "Shell Called successfully";

    } else {
        msg = "Error while calling Shell";
    }
} catch (IOException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (NullPointerException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
} finally { 
    proc.destroy(); 
}
```

The shell script is like that

```sh
sshpass -p '<password>' scp -r <userid>@<host>:/finint/inbound/financial/tenv/edw_osccl/* .
```

Once I am calling my java service, our service unable to start the shell. On contrary same shell is working fine from server command prompt. We are running our program from Unix.

Can you anyone please suggest the solution.

Comment: The shell contains only the following commands       sshpass -p '<password>' scp -r <userid>@<domain>:/finint/inbound/financial/tenv/edw_osccl/* .

Comment: is the above code written in stand alone jar?
are you getting any exceptions?
what is the data you are getting in msg variable?

Comment: We have exposed it as REST web service. Java part is present in the ear file which is deployed in the weblogic 12.2.1.1 and we are not getting any exception while calling the shell. After 45 secs of waiting status is coming as boolean "False".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code

Try looking at the above question and the code to execute shell using java

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.
      No Change in Java Code.

```
   Changed Shell Script as
   echo "Hello" >> /mnt/hmdata/output.txt
   chmod 777 /mnt/hmdata/output.txt
   export PASSWD="password"

   sshpass -f /mnt/hmdata/password scp -v -r <user><host>:<path>/<file>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the command should be `sh /mnt/hmdata/loadTest.sh` instead of `/mnt/hmdata/loadTest.sh` for you to be able to use it from your java process.
And it can be represented as `String[]`, like so:

```
String[] cmd = { "sh", "/mnt/hmdata/loadTest.sh"};
```

`public Process exec(String command)` is a convenience method for `public Process exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` witch is in turn a convenience method for `public Process exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)`, according to [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)).

It would be nice if you could share the `catch` block also just so we have the full `try-catch` block.

Comment: catch (IOException e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   proc.destroy();
  }

Comment: String[] cmd = { "sh", "/mnt/hmdata/loadTest.sh"}; ---> Not working

Comment: Does the user that runs the java service has permissions to execute the script?

Comment: Yes it has 777 permission