# Calling Shell script in java from Linux environment

Tags: java

We are using Java 8 and  have more that 10 shell scripts. We are calling 10 shell scripts in Java in Spring Boot application using below approach:

1. `Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process process = Runtime.exec(command); 
   process.waitFor();`
2. `ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(command); p.start();`

It is working fine as expected. But it is consuming server memory and finally it is creating out of memory issue. Even I closed all resource in
 finally block.

Still I am facing memory issue. Is it the right approach to call shell script in Java?

Comment: Check ProcessBuilder https://stackoverflow.com/a/526287/8258942

Comment: You should post more code. Are you intercepting the sysout/syserr of the process? How do you interact with it?

Comment: Are you sure it's an out of memory problem? Could it be a blocking issue?

Comment: I have tried with prcoss builder and I have added in my code Runtime.getRuntime().freememory()...Once my process completed and it is reducing free memory

Comment: Check ProcessBuilder stackoverflow.com/a/526287/8258942 –I have tired usig process builder but it is reducing memory every process comeplted.I have addd logger and i saw that

Comment: What the process does?
How much memory it consumed (initial, regular, max)?
Open jvisualVm and inspect memory to see what it stores, then might be you can mitigate.