# How to execute a shell script in Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, ksh

I have to run a shell script from Java in a Linux box
for eg,
Below is the script path and all parameters needed by the script.

```
"ksh /xyz/abc/data/code_base/RUN_SCRIPTS/dev/my_script.sh param1 param2 20200901 459 121"
```

Below is the code,

```
String script = "ksh /xyz/abc/data/code_base/RUN_SCRIPTS/dev/my_script.sh param1 param2 20200901 459 121";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();                       
processBuilder.command(script);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
//start() will be in try catch
process = processBuilder.start();

int exitVal = process.waitFor();

if(exitVal == 0){
   //code
}
```

**Do i need to pass the script as a List by adding each as a separate String in the List ?**
"ksh" , "/xyz/abc/data/code_base/RUN_SCRIPTS/dev/my_script.sh" , "param1" "param2" "20200901" "459" "121"

On my Windows machine, i am opening a Notepad as below and it works fine,

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", "C:/Dev/Test.txt");
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
process = processBuilder.start();
```

Will the script get executed on the Linux box properly or any more changes are required in the code ??

Comment: "Will the script get executed on the Linux box properly" does it work on your machine, for starters?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - I am coding on Windows machine and opening a Notepad using below for testing purpose. ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", "C:/Dev/Test.txt");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Unix shell script from Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code)

Comment: @VinodKhade leaving aside the specific case, you should really test it on linux anyway. Don't guess compatibility. Also, don't expect `ksh` to be installed, it's not standard on any linux distro I can think of.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - How do we handle for ksh ? Do we need to put all these in a list of String ? Like List<String> will contain "ksh" ,  "/xyz/abc/data/code_base/RUN_SCRIPTS/dev/my_script.sh" ,  "param1"  "param2" "20200901" "459" "121"

Comment: `new ProcessBuilder("ksh", "-c", "/xyz/abc/data/code_base/RUN_SCRIPTS/dev/my_script.sh", "param1", "param2", etc...);` should do the trick, but, again, test it on an actual linux system (even wsl is fine).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - Thank you so much...What is the use of "-c" ?.  Also is there a reference link which i could refer to get more understanding of this.

Comment: `-c` is for "command". It's a thing for ksh, not for `ProcessBuilder`. Here's the doc for [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start()) and here's the manual page for [`ksh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh).

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to use `Runtime.exec()` or `ProcessBuilder` to invoke a shell to run a script, but the whole process is full of pitfalls.

I would suggest reading this article:

https://www.infoworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

which explains many of these pitfalls, and how to avoid them. In particular, on Linux you'll almost certainly need to consume stdout and stderr from your shell invocation -- that's sometimes true even if the script doesn't produce any output. You'll also need to be careful how you handle spaces and special characters -- if there are any -- in the arguments to your script. The parser that Java uses for the command line blindly breaks a command line at whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Runtime.getRunTime().exec