# Call Maven from within another Maven Project

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven module and a parent of that module. Is there a way to make a call of maven on the parent from within a maven call on the child module?

To be more specific I want to make a call like

```
mvn -am -pl path/to/module clean compile
```

and this should also start a plugin like

```
mvm dependency:tree
```

The reason for this is that when I would call that plugin on the path/to/module with

```
 mvn -am -pl path/to/module dependency:tree
```

then this would only print the dependencies of this module and not of the parent and all of its child modules.

Comment: Why do you need both of this in the same Maven call?

Comment: `dependency:tree` can be attached to a phase, e.g. `clean`

Comment: @JFabianMeier I could call the one after the other, but i would love to make it as simple as possible for the people using my plugin.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea i'm aware of that, but maybe i'm not that experienced with maven to understand what it would achieve.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this that I worked out is to write a script that could be called in a plugin used by the "mvn -am -pl ..." call. This script will then call the "mvn dependency:tree" on the parent pom. I found [an SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525212/how-to-run-unix-shell-script-from-java-code) that describes how to call such scripts from within java.